# PDF editing tool implementation...erase tool issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, jspdf

I am trying to implement PDF editing tool .pdf content also getting erased.

this is the pdf loading code using js:

```
var pdf = new PDFAnnotate("pdf-container", encodeURI("http://localhost:8080/myapp/img/sample.pdf"), {

 
  onPageUpdated(page, oldData, newData) {
    console.log(page, oldData, newData);
  },
  ready() {
    console.log("Plugin initialized successfully");
  },
  scale: 1.5,
  pageImageCompression: "MEDIUM", // FAST, MEDIUM, SLOW(Helps to control the new PDF file size)
});
```

html code :

```
<div class="tool">
        <button class="tool-button"><i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Pencil" onclick="enablePencil(event)"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="tool">
        <button class="tool-button"><i class="fa fa-eraser" title="Eraser" onclick="enableEraser(event)"></i></button>
    </div>
```

here I added the html code where on click I called the function .

JS code:

```
PDFAnnotate.prototype.enablePencil = function () {
    var inst = this;
    inst.active_tool = 1;
    if (inst.fabricObjects.length > 0) {
        $.each(inst.fabricObjects, function (index, fabricObj) {
            fabricObj.isDrawingMode = true;

            
            fabricObj.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric.PencilBrush(fabricObj);

           
            fabricObj.freeDrawingBrush.color = '#000000'; // Set your desired pencil color
            fabricObj.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2; // Set your desired pencil width

            fabricObj.on('path:created', function (e) {
                
                e.path.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            });
        });
    }
}




PDFAnnotate.prototype.enableEraser = function () {
    var inst = this;
    inst.active_tool = 8;

    if (inst.fabricObjects.length > 0) {
        $.each(inst.fabricObjects, function (index, fabricObj) {
            fabricObj.isDrawingMode = true;

          
            fabricObj.freeDrawingBrush = new fabric.PencilBrush(fabricObj);

           
            fabricObj.freeDrawingBrush.color = fabricObj.backgroundColor || '#ffffff';

          
            fabricObj.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10;

            fabricObj.on('path:created', function (e) {
               
                e.path.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
            });

            fabricObj.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
              
                if (fabricObj.isDrawingMode) {
                    fabricObj.contextTop.clearRect(0, 0, fabricObj.upperCanvasEl.width, fabricObj.upperCanvasEl.height);
                    fabricObj.isDrawingMode = false;
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

this is the JS code I attached .

```
function enablePencil(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changeActiveTool(event);
    pdf.enablePencil();
}

function enableEraser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changeActiveTool(event);
    pdf.enableEraser();
}
```

pencil is working correctly but erasing pdf content also including drawing which we drawn by pencil.

can you tell me where I am doing wrong? pencil is drawing correctly only when we erase the pencil drawing which we draw through the pencil tool pdf content also erasing ..what is the solution for this ?? how can I correct it?

Comment: I removed tag [tag:java], because your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java. Please be aware that Java and JavaScript are two different languages.